# Activity crashes with onStart() but works with onCreate()

Tags: java, android

My problem is that: when I try to use the `onStart()` method to get data from a database it crashes.

I want to get the data from the database every time the Homepage activity is called and it is not possible for me to make the calls to the necessary methods from inside the `onCreate()` method.

```
public class Homepage extends FragmentActivity {

Button buttonAvailability;

ListView mDrawerList;
RelativeLayout mDrawerPane;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
String email;
View backgroundimage;
Drawable background;
ListView listView;

ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<>();
final HashMap<String, User> allUser = new HashMap<>();
final HashMap<String, Disponibilita> allDisponibilita = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_homepage);

    backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
    background.setAlpha(60);

    setupDrawerToggle();

    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home", "Go to homepage", R.drawable.homepage));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Preferences", "Change your preferences", R.drawable.ingr_icon));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Storico Attività", "Visuallizza tutte le attività passate e future", R.drawable.attivita));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Logout", "Logout from application", R.drawable.logout_icon));

    // Populate the Navigation Drawer with options
    mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    buttonAvailability = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    email = intent.getStringExtra("email");



    final UserParser userParser = new UserParser();
    final LinkedList<JSONObject> listUser = new LinkedList<>();

    //Quando avvio la homepage prendo tutti gli utenti e li inserisco in un hashmap, poi prendo l'utente che
    //mi interessa e apro la sua homepage

    UserDao.getAllUser(listUser, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        @Override

        public void onResult(Integer result) {

            if (result > 0) {
                User user = null;
                try {
                    for (JSONObject object : listUser) {
                        user = userParser.parse(object);
                        allUser.put(user.getEmail(), user);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                user = allUser.get(email);
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWelcome);
                String msg = "Welcome Dr. " + user.getSurname() + " " + user.getName();
                text.setText(msg);
                text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });


    final DisponibilitaParser dispParser = new DisponibilitaParser();
    final LinkedList<JSONObject> listDisponibilita = new LinkedList<>();


    DisponibilitaDao.getAllDisponibilita(listDisponibilita, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Integer result) {
            Disponibilita disp = null;
            //if (listDisponibilita.size()!=0) {

            Log.d("LOL", String.valueOf(listDisponibilita.size()));
            try {
                for (JSONObject object : listDisponibilita) {
                    disp = dispParser.parse(object);
                    allDisponibilita.put(disp.getId(), disp);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //}
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    final LinkedList<JSONObject> listRequest = new LinkedList<>();
    final ArrayList<Richiesta> jsonArrayConfermate = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Richiesta> jsonArrayNonConfermate = new ArrayList<>();
    final RichiestaParser ricParser = new RichiestaParser();

    RichiestaDao.getAllRichiesteRicevute(email, listRequest, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        JSONObject temp;

        @Override
        public void onResult(Integer result) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listRequest.size(); i++) {
                temp = listRequest.get(i);
                try {
                    if (temp.getInt("Confermata") == 1)
                        jsonArrayConfermate.add(ricParser.parse(temp));
                    else if (temp.getInt("Confermata") == 0)
                        jsonArrayNonConfermate.add(ricParser.parse(temp));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            setAppointmentAdapter(jsonArrayConfermate);
            setRequestAdapter(jsonArrayNonConfermate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // Drawer Item click listeners
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is the homepage!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, UserPreferences.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, HistoricalActivities.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    buttonAvailability.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandlerInsert());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();  // Always call the superclass method first
    Log.d("Homepage:","Chiamato onStart");

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Activity being restarted from stopped state
    Log.d("Homepage:","Chiamato onRestart");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first
    Log.d("Homepage:", "Chiamato onStop");
}


private void setAppointmentAdapter(ArrayList<Richiesta> appuntamenti){

    AppointmentFragment frag = (AppointmentFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.appointments);
    ArrayList<RichiestaAdapterHomepage> appointments = new ArrayList<>();

    int size = appuntamenti.size();
    if(size == 0){
        frag.setText("There are no appointments!");
    }
    else{
        frag.setText("The next appointments are:");

        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

        Disponibilita temp;
        for(Richiesta ric : appuntamenti){
            temp = allDisponibilita.get(ric.getIdDisponibilita());
            appointments.add( new RichiestaAdapterHomepage(ric.getId(), temp.getGiorno(), temp.getCitta(), allUser.get(ric.getMedicoRichiedente()).getSurname() + " " + allUser.get(ric.getMedicoRichiedente()).getName()) );
        }

        Collections.sort(appointments);
        AppointmentAdapter adapter;
        if(appointments.size() > 3)
            adapter = new AppointmentAdapter( getApplicationContext(), appointments.subList(0, 3) );
        else
            adapter = new AppointmentAdapter( getApplicationContext(), appointments );
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAppointments);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click element in position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.appointments, frag).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
}

private void setRequestAdapter(ArrayList<Richiesta> richieste){

    RequestFragment frag = (RequestFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.requests);
    ArrayList<RichiestaAdapterHomepage> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    int size = richieste.size();
    if(size == 0){
        frag.setText("There are no new requests!");
    }
    else{
        if (size == 1){
            frag.setText("There is a new request:");
        }
        else {
            frag.setText("There are " + size + " new requests:");
        }

        for(Richiesta ric : richieste){
            requests.add( new RichiestaAdapterHomepage( ric.getId(), allDisponibilita.get(ric.getIdDisponibilita()).getGiorno(), "", allUser.get(ric.getMedicoRichiedente()).getSurname() + " " + allUser.get(ric.getMedicoRichiedente()).getName()) );
        }
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        Collections.sort(requests);
        RequestAdapter adapter = new RequestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), requests, frag.getText());
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRequests);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click element in position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.requests, frag).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
}

private void setupDrawerToggle() {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if ( actionBar != null ) {
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ham_icon);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    mDrawerLayout = ( DrawerLayout ) findViewById( R.id.drawerLayout );

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            new Toolbar( Homepage.this ),
            R.string.apri,
            R.string.chiudi
    ) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed( View drawerView ) {
            super.onDrawerClosed( drawerView );
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            if ( actionBar != null ) actionBar.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened( View drawerView ) {
            if ( actionBar != null && actionBar.isShowing() ) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            super.onDrawerOpened( drawerView );
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    if(mDrawerLayout != null)
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected( int featureId, MenuItem item ) {
    switch ( item.getItemId() ) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActionBar().hide();
            break;
    }
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected( item ) || super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}


private class ClickHandlerInsert implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, Availability.class);
        intent.putExtra("email", email);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

This is the whole error stack:

```
11-09 16:17:28.584      925-925/com.example.simone.consulenzeapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.FRAGMENT.RequestFragment.setText(RequestFragment.java:23)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.Homepage.setRequestAdapter(Homepage.java:292)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.Homepage.access$100(Homepage.java:53)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.Homepage$3.onResult(Homepage.java:186)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.DAO.RichiestaDao$4.onPostExecute(RichiestaDao.java:188)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.DAO.RichiestaDao$4.onPostExecute(RichiestaDao.java:151)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is RequestFragment

```
public class RequestFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.req_list_fragment, container, false);
}

public void setText(String text) {
    TextView t = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
    t.setText(text);
}

public TextView getText(){
    TextView t = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
    return t;
}
```

}

Comment: The whole error stack would be very helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand how you can't do the same calls in `onCreate()` like in `onStart()` because they are basically in the same scope

Comment: You're trying to set the text of some `TextView`s and they're not inflated in the `onStart` method - they're created and inflated in `onCreate` - hence you get a `NullPointerException`. Fetch your data in `onStart` if you like and then wait to set the data in your views until `onCreate` has been called.
It's actually in your `Fragment` called `RequestFragment` where you call `frag.setText`.

Comment: Your code is very confusing, you might want to declare all your local variables at the start of the method for more clarity. And eventually split your code into multiple methods with adequate names (that could be reused or simply just for clarity)

Comment: @.Darwind - I have pasted RequestFragment class.
@.Andrew V - Tell me what to do...because i don't understand

Comment: Hi @Semprepiu - not sure if you got this figured out, but essentially you're trying to call `setText` on your `TextView` inside your `Fragment`, but the fragment is null where you use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.requests);`. You need to be sure, that whatever is being returned by `findFragmentById` is actually found. Where do you inflate your `Fragment`? In your `Activity`'s XML for instance?